# Postgresql - Changing numeric value to another format

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I have a database configured in `en_US` locale but, I want to do a `COPY` command saving the `NUMERIC` columns in `pt_BR` numeric format.

Can I change the numeric locale only for the active session to get the numbers in right format?

**What I get (the dot on decimal separator):**

```
database=> SELECT value FROM myTable LIMIT 1;
  value
--------
   33.9
database=> show lc_numeric;
 lc_numeric 
------------
 C
```

**What I expect (the comma on decimal separator):**

```
database=> SELECT value FROM myTable LIMIT 1;
  value
--------
   33,9
```

There's a way to change this only on the session?

I can do formatting the output manually (in a ugly way) but, I want to do this in session to do automatically:

```
database=> SELECT replace(replace(replace(round(value::numeric, 2)::varchar, '.','_'),',','.'),'_',',') FROM myTable LIMIT 1;
  value
--------
   33,9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `SET` to change the parameter only for the current session, but it won't do what you want. The data type output function ignores `lc_numeric`. That is intended.

You need to use `to_char` with the national decimal separator format code, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE).

```
SET lc_numeric = 'pt_BR';

SELECT to_char(value, '9999D9999')
FROM mytable
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Perfect. In some way, I also need to get the columns using a function to parse it by a reasonable motivation, that `lc_numeric` is ignored.